# About the statistics for the hypothesis test of the mean of two normal population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, statistical-power

Let $X = (X_1, ..., X_n)$ be an independent sample from $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y=(Y_1,...,Y_m)$ an independent sample from $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$. Consider the following hypothesis test given that $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2 = \sigma^2$ is unknow.
$$
H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 \leftrightarrow H_1: \mu_1 \neq \mu_2
$$

Notations: $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ be the mean of sample, $\mu = \frac{n}{n+m}\bar X + \frac{m}{n+m}\bar Y$ be the pooled mean of two samples.  $S_X^2 = \frac1{n-1}\sum (X_i - \bar X)^2$, $S_Y^2 = \frac1{m-1}\sum (Y_i - \bar Y)^2$, $S^2 = \frac{1}{n+m-1}\left(\sum_i (X_i -\mu)^2 + \sum_j(Y_j -\mu)^2\right)$.

Let test statistics $T_2$ be
$$
T_2 = \frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{\sqrt{\frac1n + \frac1m}\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)S_X^2 + (m-1)S_Y^2}{n+m-2}}} \sim t_{n+m-2}
$$
if $H_0$ is true by Cochran's theorem. The problem arises from the condition that $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2 = \sigma^2$. Let another test statistics $T_1$ be
$$
T_1 = \frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{\sqrt{\frac1n + \frac1m}{S}} \sim t_{n+m-1}
$$
if the $H_0$ is true. But $T_2$ is commonly used in test. My question is which is better by analyzing the power function.

To achieve that, we need to define the two different reject regions denoted $W_1$ and $W_2$ with significance level. I have done that,
$$
W_1 = \{(X, Y) \big| |T_1| > t_{n+m-1}(\alpha/2) \} \\
W_2 = \{(X, Y) \big| |T_2| > t_{n+m-2}(\alpha/2) \}
$$
where $t_k(\alpha/2)$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile of t distribution with degree $k$.

The respect power functions are $\beta_i(\mu_1, \mu_2) = P((X, Y) \in W_i), i = 1,2$.

Assume that $(\mu_1, \mu_2)$ lies in the alternative space $\Theta_1 = \{ \mu_1\neq \mu_2 \}$, $T_2$ is a non-centralized $t$ distribution but what is the distribution of $T_1$? I got stuck here since $S$ does not obey the $\chi^2$ distribution with some degree.

Btw, the key idea of comparing two statistics is to analyze the power function. Alternative method to compare them is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

This is really a question in statistics. With so many people learned about t-test during their college lectures, seldom do think deeply on conclusions they got from their textbooks.

It can be seen that the real distribution of $T_2$ in $\mathcal H_1$ is noncentral student t distribution and of $T_1$, well, difficult to get. So I choose to simulate the values of power functions in R.

```
library(ggplot2)
delta.mu=seq(-2,2,0.01)
alpha=0.05;sigma=1
T2.fun=function(rand.x,rand.y){
  sigma_1=sqrt(((n-1)*var(rand.x)+(m-1)*var(rand.y))/(n+m-2))
  return((mean(rand.x)-mean(rand.y))/(sqrt(1/m+1/n)*sigma_1))
} 

T1.fun=function(rand.x,rand.y){
  pooled.mean=mean(c(rand.x,rand.y))
  sigma_2=sqrt((sum((rand.x-pooled.mean)^2)+sum((rand.y-pooled.mean)^2))/(n+m-1))
  return((mean(rand.x)-mean(rand.y))/(sqrt(1/m+1/n)*sigma_2))
}

set.seed(1)

n=100;m=200
# reject region bound
t2=qt(1-alpha/2,n+m-2)
t1=qt(1-alpha/2,n+m-1)

pesudo.power.value1=c();pesudo.power.value2=c()
for(i in delta.mu){
  T2=c();T1=c()
  for(j in 1:1000){
    # μ1-μ2=i
    X=rnorm(n,i,sigma)
    Y=rnorm(m,0,sigma)
    
    T1=c(T1,T1.fun(X,Y))
    T2=c(T2,T2.fun(X,Y))
  }
  # power function value
  value1=mean(abs(T1) > t1)
  value2=mean(abs(T2) > t2)
  
  pesudo.power.value1=c(pesudo.power.value1,value1)
  pesudo.power.value2=c(pesudo.power.value2,value2)
}

df1=data.frame(power.value=c(pesudo.power.value1,pesudo.power.value2),
              x=delta.mu,method=gl(2,length(delta.mu)))
ggplot(df1,aes(x=x,y=power.value,color=method))+geom_smooth()

set.seed(1)
n=4;m=5
# reject region bound
t2=qt(1-alpha/2,n+m-2)
t1=qt(1-alpha/2,n+m-1)

pesudo.power.value1=c();pesudo.power.value2=c()
for(i in delta.mu){
  T1=c();T2=c()
  for(j in 1:1000){
    # μ1-μ2=i
    X=rnorm(n,i,sigma)
    Y=rnorm(m,0,sigma)
    
    T1=c(T1,T1.fun(X,Y))
    T2=c(T2,T2.fun(X,Y))
  }
  # power function value
  value1=mean(abs(T1) > t1)
  value2=mean(abs(T2) > t2)
  
  pesudo.power.value1=c(pesudo.power.value1,value1)
  pesudo.power.value2=c(pesudo.power.value2,value2)
}

df2=data.frame(power.value=c(pesudo.power.value1,pesudo.power.value2),
              x=delta.mu,method=gl(2,length(delta.mu)))
ggplot(df2,aes(x=x,y=power.value,color=method))+geom_smooth()
```

[image: n=100; m=200]

[image: n=4; m=5]

As you can see, in large sample size condition these two statistics are similar in test power; for a relatively small sample size, the traditional statistics we use ($T_1$) has a higher power in test. So there are reasons why we choose $T_2$: it drives $X$ and $Y$ clearly in the form of statistics which is better than take them as a whole in $T_1$.

Comment: Could you add the link @Xier?

Comment: Sorry for the trick. SungManhin is one of my classmates. The OP is posted by us.

Comment: Okay @xier. No problem.

Comment: I'm confused about something...my read of your statement of the problem is that the variances are indeed the same for both distributions $X$ and $Y$, but the value of that variance is unknown.  ¿Is this correct?

Comment: @GreggH, yes, we assume that the variance of the two population coincides and aim to investige the power with respect to the two different statistics.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clever question, and demonstrates careful consideration of the algorithms we use and why.  And the analysis of power is indeed a key motivator in deciding which test to use.

However, in this example, the distribution of the proposed test statistic is not really the issue.  The problem is that the estimate for the shared variance (standard deviation) that you propose will cause the test-statistic to "break-down".  In brief, once the distance between the population means becomes too large, that difference will dominate the value of $S$.  In fact, this value will essentially become $S\approx\frac{|\mu_1 - \mu_2|}{2}$.

Thus, your value for $T_1 = 2 \sqrt{\frac{nm}{n+m}}$ doesn't actually depend on the values in your data set, but on the sample sizes of your data set.

Now, one could argue that for large differences, $T_2$ will be highly powered and $T_1$ will be "always" powered to detect a difference (for any reasonable $\alpha$).  So, I believe the real question here might be about the difference between the tests is when there is an appropriately small difference in the population means.  (In truth, this "answer" is probably more appropriately a comment...but it was too long to include as a comment.)

Comment: I'm not sure why I found this question so fascinating...but I keep coming back and playing with it in my free time...my new query for this overall question is regarding what happens with very small samples and what happens with small unbalanced samples.  (As might be gleaned from my post, I am only focusing on very small differences between group means.)  Preliminary results indicate that the conventional ANOVA t-test outperforms the revised t-test in all small sample scenarios.

Comment: Well it is a interesting point to note that $S$ reduces to a constant by CLT. I prefer a more rigorous proof that $T_2$ is indeed better than $T_1$.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you need to rely on CLT for the asymptotic behavior of S.  The within variance become negligible as the mean difference grows.

Comment: oh, I got it since the sample will center at the mean with a high probability by Chebyshev's inequality. Can this prove the asymptotic property of $S$? BTW what I mean before this comment is also the same intution that the sample lies in an NBHD of the mean thus the pooled variance $S$ will behave nicely i.e. $\approx |\mu_1=\mu_2|/2$ as the sample size goes sufficiently large and the difference of the mean is large but not neccessarily tends to infinity.